# How to find all the blue pixels and the location of the two boundaries in blue pixels?

Tags: matlab, indexing, find

I want to find per column the first and last blue pixels and them find the other boundary ( first and last blue pixel rows) inside this rows achieved before.

I made the alterations based on the previous answeers, but now I have this error when it tries to find the bif_first and last: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch. bif_first2(2,z)=find(dx(:,z)==1,2,'first');

What is wrong? Please see my code below:

```
 rgbImage_blue=zeros(size(movingRegistered));

  lumen_first=zeros(1,size(movingRegistered,2)); lumen_last=zeros(1,size(movingRegistered,2)); bif_first=zeros(1,size(movingRegistered,2)); bif_last=zeros(1,size(movingRegistered,2)); bif_last2=zeros(2,size(movingRegistered,2)); bif_first2=zeros(2,size(movingRegistered,2));

    blue=cat(3,0,0,255); 
ix=all(bsxfun(@eq,movingRegistered,blue),3);% find all the blue pixels, and put them at 1 % logical array of where blue pixels are dx=[zeros(1,size(movingRegistered,2));diff(ix)]; % zeros to make the same number of columns and rows % the difference by row for all columns
 nTops=sum(dx==1); % the transitions to blue
 nBots=sum(dx==-1); % and from blue... % see if are consistent; if not, something's not right in image
 if(nTops~=nBots), error('Mismatch in Top/Bottom'),end

 for z=1:1:size(movingRegistered,2);
    if  nTops(1,z)==2; bifurcation=false;lumen=true; %only existis two boundaries no bifurcation
    lumen_first(1,z)=find(ix(:,z)==1,1,'first');
    lumen_last(1,z)=find(ix(:,z)==1,1,'last');
    end
    if nTops(1,z)>2;
    bifurcation=true;
    lumen_first(1,z)=find(ix(:,z)==1,1,'first');
    lumen_last(1,z)=find(ix(:,z)==1,1,'last');
    bif_first2(2,z)=find(dx(:,z)==1,2,'first');
    bif_first(1,z)=bif_first2(2,z);
    bif_last2(2,z)=find(dx(:,z)==1,2,'last');
    bif_last(1,z)=bif_last2(2,z);
    end
 end
```

[image]

Comment: Try something like `ix=(movingRegistered(:,:,1)==blue(1))&(movingRegistered(:,:,2)==blue(2))&(movingRegistered(:,:,3)==blue(3))`

Comment: Any reason why  `blue` is not defined as `[0 0 255].'` ?

Comment: Yes is 255 my mistake!!

Comment: Please do not edit your question with the answer @Daniel provided as it's then a completely different question! If the answer solved your problem mark it as accepted and ask another question if something else is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are comparing a n*m*3 image with a 3*1 vector. This operation is not defined.

Use this code:

```
blue=cat(3,0,0,250)
ix=all(bsxfun(@eq,movingRegistered,blue),3)
```

Images in Matlab use the third dimension for color, that's why I created `blue` to be a 1*1*3 vector. Now this vector is compared to the image, using bsxfun to expand the vector to match the image size. This operation compares each color channel individually, so `all` is used to collect the data for all three channels.

Comment: You are missing a bracket, aren't you...?